# Promtail Loki logs to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, connectivity, grafana-loki, promtail

I have an environment with both windows VMs and a k8s cluster. **the only connectivity available in the environment is from the k8s cluster to the windows VMs and not the opposite**.

Now, I need to get the logs from my Windows VMs into the k8s cluster's elasticsearch.

How do you think I can get the logs from the Windows virtual machines (VMs) to the elasticsearch cluster?

I was thinking of putting a promtail instance on the Windows VMs and a Loki instance on the K8s cluster so that the logs from promtail could be pulled from Loki and then forward to elasticsearch.

Does my resolution meet the requirement?
Do you know of any other ways to deal with my requirement?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi \`Raz Mabaari\` you can simply add the firewall rules so that the communication can happen between your windows VM and the kubernetes cluster, even if you are trying to deploy Promtail and send logs to elasticsearch using it you need to open certain ports. Add more details so that we can assist you and stackoverflow is not a place to seek recommendations, please follow the guidelines attached for more clarification https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi kranthiveer-dontineni, Unfortuanly I cannot add firewall rules to allow it, I need a resoultion in which I could just pull logs from the k8s cluster and not retrive them.
Please tell me what kind of other information would I be needed to help me address.
Thank you.

Comment: Since you can't modify the ports using some tools like promtail for sending the logs to elasticsearch might not work since you need to make changes to firewall rules, Instead you can try using some cloud storages like gcs and you can pull logs from there.. Can you explain your application architecture in detail and why it's not possible to add firewall rules..?